# Creating own object storage similar to shared preferences

Tags: android, performance, object, storage, sharedpreferences

I just want to ask if it is advisable to create a class that works like SharedPreferences. The only difference is that this class will store multiple custom objects that I create within the whole app. Then I link this said class to my application class, therefore making it accessible throughout my whole app.

For example... I create my Application class, naming it ApplicationCore(AC). Then I create my own storage class, naming it ApplicationStorage(AS). Inside my AC I have a get/set method to access the AS. Then inside the AS, I have multiple get/set/clear methods for getting/storing of different object classes to different HashMaps.

I would really appreciate your feedback on this. If you have different opinions/methods on how to do this, feel free to share. I already got bummed at using gson since it cannot store object classes with Sqlite functions in them. Any idea would be awesome help.

Comment: I just know I'm missing the point...if you can parcel/serialise your objects to store them in your own preferences, then why not in SharedPreferences?  Or let me spin that, what is the limitation you are hitting?  Where does JSON come into it?

Comment: If I store my parcelized object in my preferences, can I retrieve it back again? I haven't tried preferences yet, just shared preferences. Is there a difference? In shared preferences you cannot store objects, just primitive data like String, int, etc. I found a work-around that using gson. Now I thought that would solve it, but adding my own sql insert/update queries on the custom object classes didn't make gson store it. So that was a waste. If I said something wrong, feel free to correct me. Oh btw, I want the store activity data on a temporary storage on said activity.